# Unable to get redis key-value pair using Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, http-headers

I am currently making a post request to my Node app to get the key and value from `index.html`.
`client.set` is used to set the key-value and similarly `client.get` to get all the key-values. However, I am not able to `console.log()` the values for trying to send the response twice.

**Error:**

```
_http_outgoing.js:485
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Below is the logic I have used to fetch the values of all keys.

**app.js**

```
var client      = redis.createClient(); 
var port = 6379;
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var client = redis.createClient(port, host);
router.post('/route1', function(req, res)
{ 
    var valarr=[];
    keyname= req.body.keyname;
    valuename= req.body.valuename;
    console.log(keyname);
    console.log(valuename);
    
    client.set(keyname, valuename, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(reply);
    });

    client.keys('*', function(err, keys) {
        console.log(keys);
        for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            client.get(keys[i], function (error, value) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                console.log(value);
                valarr.push(value);           
            });  
        }
        res.json({result1:keys, result2: valarr});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting ERROR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT is because you are invoking `res.json()` within a for loop, causing your node server to attempt to set response headers in subsequent `res.json()` invocations after a response from the first `res.json()` has already been sent to the client.

If you want to console.log the values for all the redis keys you are scanning, I suggest storing them in an array and returning that array at the bottom of your endpoint.

Comment: If you look at the new edits. I am storing the values in an array and then returning the array. How ever the array returned is blank and when i include it inside the function `client.get(keys[i]...`. I get `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`.

Comment: In your `res.json` you should be returning your array `valarr`, not `value`, which only exists within the callback of your `client.get`.

Comment: The `valarr` which is being sent back to the ajax call is empty. As the array is getting appended with new values inside the function and not accessible outside.

Comment: And when I include the `res.json()` inside the function which also puts it inside the `for loop `and the response is sent more than once. Thus throwing HTTP_HEADER_ERROR